# Actors collision doesn't collide with other actors/walls

Tags: c++, collision, unreal-engine4

I have been trying to work out a (probably very common) issue in regards to collision.

I have a Handgun Actor (BP_Handgun -> Handgun.cpp/.h) which is attached to my MainCharacter Class via a socket. Within BP_Handgun, I have the collision presets set to BlockAllDynamic and seems to collide with my enemy which is a Character. However, with the BSP and Actors (cubes made to look like walls) I have in my scene, the gun doesn't seem to collide with them at all and just clips through.

Just wanted to add, I have the Handgun attached to my MainCharacter.cpp (BP_MainCharacter) like so

```
void AMainCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    check(GEngine != nullptr);

    Handgun = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AHandgun>(HandgunClass);
    Handgun->AttachToComponent(GetMesh(), FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform, TEXT("WeaponSocket"));
    Handgun->SetOwner(this);
}
```

I have a feeling it might be to do with AttachToComponent() using the components collision rather than itself?
[image]

Collision Presets
[image]

Comment: Please edit the post with the relevant code.

Comment: There isn't really any code in relating to this. I've set the collision in BP_Handgun to BlockAllDynamic and it collides with my ZombieBasic Actor Character, but doesn't collide with BSP or Basic geometry placed into the scene.

Comment: If there is no equivalent C++ code, can you remove the C++ tag? Also do see this related article: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/23011/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-collisions-for-a-bsp.html

Comment: I have read that article, but it doesn't solve my issue. My Characters Capsule collider/Static mesh will collide with BSP/Actors (used as floor, walls, etc). But the weapon does not and clips through them as shown in the image above but it will collide with the enemy which is placed into the level.

Comment: What value is set for Collision Enabled, Collision Responses and Object Responses? https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/Collision/Reference/

Comment: I have added some C++ code which I think may be causing some sort of error. But I have tried all the different collision presets and nothing.

Comment: Can you update the post with the current values for presets? Also, I think what you need to do is to compare the properties of enemy actor and this wall. If it collides with enemy, enemy must have some properties which allows the collision which the wall doesn't.

Comment: Updated the post with the collision presets for each object,.

Comment: Related: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/Collision/HowTo/AddSimpleCollision/ https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/Collision/Overview/

Comment: The handgun itself I believe is a skeletal mesh not static. I have a feeling it's the way I've setup the component within BP_Handgun and how it is attached to the MainCharacter.

Comment: I seem to have found a way around this, but it comes with another small issue. Using a translucent material, I enabled 'Disable Depth Test' which gives the illusion of the actor colliding with the walls. However, with this enabled and moving close to objects the actor/material seems to be jittery/blurry.

Comment: I think you main character has a capsule collider as you stated in the comments above. I think you should see if the collider also covers the hand gun too and not just the character.

Comment: The way how I saw it done, character would react to near-collision (collider touches wall? gun overlaps wall?) and would lower\lift or adjust the gun so it wouldn't clip in wall. The jitter\blur in case of clipping with alpha ordering enabled is  anti-aliasing blur, afaik (and is performance issue as well).

Comment: @kiner_shah - The characters collider does not encapsulate the handgun. I did try making the capsule bigger but this introduced another issue of colliders fighting and the character would occasionally be catapulted across the world.

Swift-FridayPie - Having the gun move either up/down when it comes into contact with a wall is something I would implement further down the line. Just currently looking for a cheap/easy fix for now (ideally). The Handgun though does collide with the enemy BP, just not walls for some reason.

Comment: @George_H, you may also be able to find better response for your problem on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your BP_Handgun's object type appears to be set to 'WorldStatic' as well as ArenaWall. I would expect that BP_Handgun's object type to be something like 'WorldDynamic'. There maybe some early filtering that is happening that does not check collisions for pairs of 'WorldStatic' objects.